# Jquery---Select all the text box with given class

Tags: jquery

html

```
<input type="text" class="required" />
```

now i want to select all the text-box with this given class name and want to check whether particular text box has another class called "error" which i am adding dynamically.

```
 $(".required).each(function() {
     if(this.hasClass('error'){
          alert("has error class");
     }
 }
```

but not working as expected.. how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have a typo a missing `"` and also you need to wrap `this` as the jQuery object

```
$(".required").each(function() {
     //Iterate through each element
     if($(this).hasClass('error')){
          alert("has error class");
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution:

```
<input type="text" class="required" />
<input type="text" class="required" />
<input type="text" class="required error" />

<script>
      $('.required').each(function(index, value){
          if($(value).hasClass('error')){
              alert("has error class");
          }
      });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have many syntax errors.

1. Closing quote missing of selector.
2. Use `$(this)` with hasClass instead of this. As `this represents javascript object` while `$(this) is jquery object` and `hasClass is jquery function` not javascript.
3. Closing parenthesis of if statement is missing.
4. Closing parenthesis of each function is also missing.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XmjkR/1/)**

```
$(".required").each(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('error')) {
        alert("has error class");
    }     
})​;
```

Comment: When I looked at your answer the code was identical. Right suggestions now, though your code doesn't show all your fixes

Comment: Yes missed some, now updated the code, Thanks for pointing.

Answer (score 0):

No need to loop through using `.each`.

`$(".required.error")` will give you all the elements having both classes.

Comment: Your answer aside, why did you edit the question to fix the error?

Comment: @Daedalus - Corrected the typo in the question. Why?

Comment: Well, you have no way of knowing if that typo existed in the original code.  As it stands, you kind of blur that line, though the OP's acceptance shows they did have that error in their original code.  If I were you, I'd reverse that edit.

Comment: You are right. I thought it was a typo by the OP and edited it to improve the quality of the question! Didn't think it was the actual code.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error, namely you're missing a closing bracket after your `hasClass` call:

```
 $(".required").each(function() {
     if($(this).hasClass('error')){
          alert("has error class");
     }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

You have an error into your code, try this:

```
$(".required").each(function() {
     if($(this).hasClass('error'){
          alert("has error class");
     }
 }
```